# Converting bulk xml to separate csv using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I have a Power Shell script that queries an xml document and outputs the results to a csv file. The script works, but I need to apply it to multiple xml files in a folder, then output the results as a separate csv for each XML with the same XML name. How can this script be modified to do this?

```
PROCESS 
{ 
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\sample.xml) #Sample XML

$xml.log.event | Select-object @(
@{l="times";e={$_.time}},
@{l="type";e={$_.type}},
@{l="user";e={$_.user}},
@{l="place";e={$_.place}},
@{l="message";e={$_.message}}) |
Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Do you have a directory of xml files or something?

Comment: Hi.. Yes I've got a directory with multiple xml files in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a directory:

```
$ToProcess = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp' -Filter '*.xml'

ForEach ($File in $ToProcess)
{
    [Xml]$Xml = Get-Content -Path $File.FullName

    $Xml.log.event | Select-Object -Property @(
        @{Name='Times';Expression={$_.Time}},
        @{Name='Type'; Expression={$_.Type}},
        @{Name='User'; Expression={$_.User}},
        @{Name='Place';Expression={$_.Place}},
        @{Name='Message';Expression={$_.Message}}
    ) | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\$($File.BaseName).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```